# Font error on GIMP affter installed

Tags: gimp

I have an issue with the font on GIMP after installation.
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
GIMP version: 2.10.36
[image]

Comment: How did you install 2.10.36? Flatpak? What is your Locale set to?

Comment: @xenoid yes, I installed it via Flatpak, and it located in /snap/bin/gimp

Comment: What locale? Usually this is because you are using a language/character set which isn't supported by the UI font.

Comment: Fixed it, seem I have two versions of GIMP on my machine, just removed the GIMP version of Snap and only use the stable version on Flatpak. Thank you for your help.